# Show only columns where there is at least one cell of specified color

Tags: excel, filter

I have a very big excel table where some cells are red. I like to use special filter for blending out all the columns where there are not red cells present.

I know how to use filtering by color for a separate column, but the problem is that I have around 100 columns, and to set the same filter for each column takes too much time. So I am looking how to simplify this task.

Thanks for any advices!

Comment: Are the cells red because of conditional formatting, or manually colored red?

Comment: Not it is just an output of some program, there is no any condition in background